# How to convert LINQ nested Selectmany to SQL Regular Statements

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I know it's ain't gonna be easy but I'm stuck on this and can't move on.
I have this linq

```
    var resourceItems = queryable
                .Select(ri => new ResourceItemDto
                {
                    Id = ri.Id,
                    CreationDate = ri.CreationDate,
                    ParentId = ri.FolderId,
                    Name = ri.Name,
                    Type = ri.ResourceType,
                    Url = ri.Url,
                    Size = ri.Size,
                    MediaAssetUuid = ri.MediaAssetUuid,
                    Blob = ri.Blob,
                    Container = ri.Container,
                    GroupId = ri.GroupId,
                    Status = (ResourceItemStatus) ri.Status,
                    Progress =
                        ri.EncodingJobs.SelectMany(j => j.EncodingTasks).Any()
                            ? (ri.EncodingJobs.SelectMany(j => j.EncodingTasks).Sum(t => (decimal?) t.Progress)/
                               ri.EncodingJobs.SelectMany(j => j.EncodingTasks).Count() ?? 0M)
                            : 0M,
                    Uuid = ri.Uuid,
                    CreatedBy =
                        new UserDto
                        {
                            Id = ri.User.Id,
                            UserName = ri.User.UserName,
                            FirstName = ri.User.FirstName,
                            LastName = ri.User.LastName
                        }
                });
```

And now the task is to move this into a SP and I don't want to take the sql generated by the EF, it's clumsy and machine-generated.

I ended up having this:

```
SELECT
    ri.Id
    ,ri.CreationDate
    ,ri.FolderId
    ,ri.Name
    ,ri.ResourceType
    ,ri.Url
    ,ri.Size
    ,ri.MediaAssetUuid
    ,ri.Blob
    ,ri.Container
    ,ri.GroupId
    --, (sql_expression) AS Progress
    ,ri.Uuid
    ,u.Id AS UserId
    ,u.UserName
    ,u.FirstName
    ,u.LastName
FROM ResourceItem ri
INNER JOIN ResourceItemsTree rit ON ri.FolderId = rit.Id
INNER JOIN [User] u ON u.Id = ri.CreatedBy
WHERE
    ri.IsDeleted = CAST(0 as BIT)
```

Now my problem is that Progress column calculation which includes a few repeating SelectMany statements and I don't know how to do with this.
Any help is really appreciated, guys.

There's a `EncodingJobs` table having a FK ResourceItemId (0 to many) to the resourceItem table, and there's another table EncodingTask with a FK EncodingJobId (the same 0 to many).

This is what EF generates:

```
SELECT 
[Project4].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project4].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate], 
[Project4].[FolderId] AS [FolderId], 
[Project4].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project4].[ResourceType] AS [ResourceType], 
[Project4].[Url] AS [Url], 
[Project4].[Size] AS [Size], 
[Project4].[MediaAssetUuid] AS [MediaAssetUuid], 
[Project4].[Blob] AS [Blob], 
[Project4].[Container] AS [Container], 
[Project4].[GroupId] AS [GroupId], 
[Project4].[Status] AS [Status], 
CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[EncodingJob] AS [Extent12]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[EncodingTask] AS [Extent13] ON [Extent12].[Id] = [Extent13].[JobId]
    WHERE [Project4].[Id] = [Extent12].[ResourceItemId]
)) THEN CASE WHEN ([Project4].[C1] /  CAST( [Project4].[C2] AS decimal(19,0)) IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as decimal(18)) ELSE [Project4].[C3] /  CAST( [Project4].[C4] AS decimal(19,0)) END ELSE cast(0 as decimal(18)) END AS [C1], 
[Project4].[Uuid] AS [Uuid], 
[Project4].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
[Project4].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Project4].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Project4].[LastName] AS [LastName]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project3].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project3].[FolderId] AS [FolderId], 
    [Project3].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project3].[ResourceType] AS [ResourceType], 
    [Project3].[Url] AS [Url], 
    [Project3].[Size] AS [Size], 
    [Project3].[MediaAssetUuid] AS [MediaAssetUuid], 
    [Project3].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Project3].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate], 
    [Project3].[GroupId] AS [GroupId], 
    [Project3].[Container] AS [Container], 
    [Project3].[Blob] AS [Blob], 
    [Project3].[Uuid] AS [Uuid], 
    [Project3].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
    [Project3].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    [Project3].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Project3].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
    [Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project3].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project3].[C3] AS [C3], 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM  [dbo].[EncodingJob] AS [Extent10]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[EncodingTask] AS [Extent11] ON [Extent10].[Id] = [Extent11].[JobId]
        WHERE [Project3].[Id] = [Extent10].[ResourceItemId]) AS [C4]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Project2].[FolderId] AS [FolderId], 
        [Project2].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Project2].[ResourceType] AS [ResourceType], 
        [Project2].[Url] AS [Url], 
        [Project2].[Size] AS [Size], 
        [Project2].[MediaAssetUuid] AS [MediaAssetUuid], 
        [Project2].[Status] AS [Status], 
        [Project2].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate], 
        [Project2].[GroupId] AS [GroupId], 
        [Project2].[Container] AS [Container], 
        [Project2].[Blob] AS [Blob], 
        [Project2].[Uuid] AS [Uuid], 
        [Project2].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
        [Project2].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
        [Project2].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
        [Project2].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
        [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
        (SELECT 
            SUM([Extent9].[Progress]) AS [A1]
            FROM  [dbo].[EncodingJob] AS [Extent8]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[EncodingTask] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent8].[Id] = [Extent9].[JobId]
            WHERE [Project2].[Id] = [Extent8].[ResourceItemId]) AS [C3]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Project1].[FolderId] AS [FolderId], 
            [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
            [Project1].[ResourceType] AS [ResourceType], 
            [Project1].[Url] AS [Url], 
            [Project1].[Size] AS [Size], 
            [Project1].[MediaAssetUuid] AS [MediaAssetUuid], 
            [Project1].[Status] AS [Status], 
            [Project1].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate], 
            [Project1].[GroupId] AS [GroupId], 
            [Project1].[Container] AS [Container], 
            [Project1].[Blob] AS [Blob], 
            [Project1].[Uuid] AS [Uuid], 
            [Project1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
            [Project1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
            [Project1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
            [Project1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
            [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
            (SELECT 
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM  [dbo].[EncodingJob] AS [Extent6]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[EncodingTask] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[Id] = [Extent7].[JobId]
                WHERE [Project1].[Id] = [Extent6].[ResourceItemId]) AS [C2]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                [Extent1].[FolderId] AS [FolderId], 
                [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
                [Extent1].[ResourceType] AS [ResourceType], 
                [Extent1].[Url] AS [Url], 
                [Extent1].[Size] AS [Size], 
                [Extent1].[MediaAssetUuid] AS [MediaAssetUuid], 
                [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
                [Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate], 
                [Extent1].[GroupId] AS [GroupId], 
                [Extent1].[Container] AS [Container], 
                [Extent1].[Blob] AS [Blob], 
                [Extent1].[Uuid] AS [Uuid], 
                [Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
                [Extent2].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                [Extent3].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
                [Extent3].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
                (SELECT 
                    SUM([Extent5].[Progress]) AS [A1]
                    FROM  [dbo].[EncodingJob] AS [Extent4]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[EncodingTask] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[Id] = [Extent5].[JobId]
                    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent4].[ResourceItemId]) AS [C1]
                FROM   [dbo].[ResourceItem] AS [Extent1]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[User] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CreatedBy] = [Extent2].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[User] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[CreatedBy] = [Extent3].[Id]
                WHERE ([Extent1].[IsDeleted] <> cast(1 as bit)) AND ([Extent1].[FolderId] = @p__linq__0)
            )  AS [Project1]
        )  AS [Project2]
    )  AS [Project3]
)  AS [Project4]
```

Comment: I know it may look clumsy, but I have read it is very efficient base on the index's and such defined in your database.  If your schema is in good shape, it might be better than generating another one without knowing your defined indexes.

Comment: I may guess you've got an EncodingJob table (related to ResourceItem) and an EncodingTask table (related to EncodingJob) ? How are they related (field names would help).

Comment: @Raphael, I've just added that info at the end of the question. Lemme know if it's not enough.

Comment: That's a good way to misuse your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to think what you are looking for.
In this case its the total of the progress / count, grouped per resourceItem.

The following should be about right, but the IDs might need correcting!
This uses a common table expression (SQL Server) but could easily be rewritten to a subquery

```
;WITH prog AS
(
    SELECT 
        ej.ResourceItemId,
        SUM(et.Progress) / COUNT(*) AS totalProg
    FROM EncodingJobs ej
    JOIN EncodingTasks et ON ej.Id = et.EncodingJobId
    GROUP BY
        ej.ResourceItemId
)
SELECT
    ri.Id
    ,ri.CreationDate
    ,ri.FolderId
    ,ri.Name
    ,ri.ResourceType
    ,ri.Url
    ,ri.Size
    ,ri.MediaAssetUuid
    ,ri.Blob
    ,ri.Container
    ,ri.GroupId
    ,ISNULL(prog.totalProg, 0) AS Progress
    ,ri.Uuid
    ,u.Id AS UserId
    ,u.UserName
    ,u.FirstName
    ,u.LastName
FROM ResourceItem ri
INNER JOIN ResourceItemsTree rit ON ri.FolderId = rit.Id
INNER JOIN [User] u ON u.Id = ri.CreatedBy
LEFT JOIN prog ON ri.Id = prog.ResourceItemId
WHERE
    ri.IsDeleted = CAST(0 as BIT)
```

Comment: Both replies work, thanks guys! I just like CTEs personally. ResourceItemsTree is one btw so I coupled them by a comma - looks very nice ;)

Comment: James I'm just wondering What the hell EF generates for this query?? it does a lot of unnecessary selects for checks..it's probably the complexity of linq to T-SQL translation..moreover with all those features T-SQl provides, I think EF team sticks with pure SQL as much as possible.

Comment: Entity framework tends to go for a fairly literal translation of the LINQ, `.Any(...)` tends to get translated to `WHERE EXISTS(...)` for example. It would rarely use a group by in the generated sql unless its there in the LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Well this should be something like that.

Cast the count to decimal if Progress is an integer, to avoid integer division.If not, you can avoid the cast

```
SELECT
    ri.Id
    ,ri.CreationDate
    ,ri.FolderId
    ,ri.Name
    ,ri.ResourceType
    ,ri.Url
    ,ri.Size
    ,ri.MediaAssetUuid
    ,ri.Blob
    ,ri.Container
    ,ri.GroupId
    coalesce(sum(et.Progress) / cast(count(*) as decimal(18,2)), 0) AS Progress
    ,ri.Uuid
    ,u.Id AS UserId
    ,u.UserName
    ,u.FirstName
    ,u.LastName
FROM ResourceItem ri
INNER JOIN ResourceItemsTree rit ON ri.FolderId = rit.Id
INNER JOIN [User] u ON u.Id = ri.CreatedBy
LEFT JOIN EncodingJob ej on ej.ResourceItemId= ri.Id
LEFT JOIN EncodingTask et on et.JobId = ej.Id
WHERE
    ri.IsDeleted = 0
group by
ri.Id
    ,ri.CreationDate
    ,ri.FolderId
    ,ri.Name
    ,ri.ResourceType
    ,ri.Url
    ,ri.Size
    ,ri.MediaAssetUuid
    ,ri.Blob
    ,ri.Container
    ,ri.GroupId
    ,ri.Uuid
    ,u.Id AS UserId
    ,u.UserName
    ,u.FirstName
    ,u.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach SQL Server Profiler to my database and run the application. SQL Server Profiler will capture the SQL that is being run on the database. You can then use that SQL as a starting point for your stored procedure.

[SQL Server Profiler Tutorial](http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=sql%20server%20profiler%20tutorial&FORM=VIRE2#view=detail&mid=B0F9F3DA5F06C7D9D697B0F9F3DA5F06C7D9D697)

Comment: I did it first, Sean, but it generates a lot of nested queries that I couldn't refac into a human-friendly code :) I can post it if it helps, guys.

Comment: THE SQL that was generated is what I was looking for but it looks like you have a solid answer to your question now.